# having some issue with the "@hotwired/turbo-rails" in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

You can mark the path "@hotwired/turbo-rails" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.

this is the error and i want to know how to mark this path as external.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that the "@hotwired/turbo-rails" package is causing issues with your bundle.

1. **One way** to resolve this error is to mark the package as external, which will exclude it from the bundle and prevent the error from occurring.

- You can do this by modifying your Webpack configuration file, most likely located in the config/webpack folder of your Rails application.
- Inside the configuration file, you should find a section called "externals" that is used to define packages that should be excluded from the bundle.

You can add "@hotwired/turbo-rails" to the externals list like this:

```
externals: {
  "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "commonjs @hotwired/turbo-rails"
}
```

2. **Alternatively[I resolved mine by following these changings]**,

- you can use Webpacker's add_externals method to accomplish this in the

> config/webpack/environment.js file

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.addExternals({
  "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "commonjs @hotwired/turbo-rails"
})
module.exports = environment
```

Be sure to restart your development server after making changes to the configuration file for the changes to take effect.

Another way to resolve the issue is to check if the package is installed and if it is the correct version, you can use yarn list or npm list to check the version of packages installed.

If the package version is incorrect or not compatible with your application, you should uninstall it and install the correct version that is compatible with your application.

It's also possible that the package is no longer needed or that you are using an outdated method that is not compatible with the current version of Rails. In this case, you might want to consider removing it from your application entirely and replacing it with a more updated solution.

Comment: I think the issue is that he doesnt want to just like stop the error, he wants to resolve it. This is not an external lib, it will be always in the node_modules dir.

Comment: Rails 7 doesn't have webpacker